# PowerShell ISE Identifier that starts with is too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am running SQL Server Management Studio: version 15.0.18358.0

With the help of the stackoverflow community, I wrote the following code which I hope to use to automate daily a table in my SQL server. I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong or what I need to look for to remedy my error. I'm attempting to import the txt file 'ED_TO_BED_DAILY' into SQL. The code runs but I am getting an error which reads:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The identifier that starts with 'TRACK_GROUP  DISCHARGE_LOCATION  PT_NAME PT_MRN  PT_FIN  ADM_LOC ROOM    BED ARRIVAL_MONTH
> ADMIT_BED_ORDERED   ADMIT_BED_ASSIGNED  ADMIT_B' is too long. Maximum length is 128."

Here is my code:

```
Function AutoImportCommaFlatFiles($location, $file, $extension, $server, $database)
{
    $full = $location + $file + $extension
    $all = Get-Content $full
    $columns = $all[0]
    $columns = $columns.Replace(" ","")
    $columns = $columns.Replace(",","] VARCHAR(100), [")
    $table = "CREATE TABLE " + $file + "([" + $columns + "] VARCHAR(100))"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $buildTable = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $insertData = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + $server  + ";Database=" + $database + ";integrated security=true"
    $buildTable.CommandText = $table
    $buildTable.Connection = $connection
    ## Added to function
    $x = 0
    $insertData.CommandText = "EXECUTE stp_CommaBulkInsert @1,@2"
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@1", $full)
    $insertData.Parameters.Add("@2", $file)
    $insertData.Connection = $connection
    $connection.Open()
    $buildTable.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
    ## Added to function
    $x = 1
    if ($x = 1)
    {
        $connection.Open()
        $insertData.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $connection.Close()
    }
}
AutoImportCommaFlatFiles -location "Q:\Data Requests\ED TO BED TEST\" -file "ED_TO_BED_DAILY" -extension ".txt" -server "ENTSQL01LSNR" -database "EMTCQIData"
```

Here is are the format of the variables within the SQL table:

[image]

Here is what a snippet of the flat file looks like:
[image]

Comment: Put in a line: `Write-Host $table` to see what SQL code is being generated. I suspect that the first line of the file is tab-delimited, not comma-delimited.

Comment: @RichMoss it is TAB, with that being said, how should I change my code. I suspect something in this line  $columns = $columns.Replace(",","] VARCHAR(100), [")   I added a snippet picture to my question above to show what the flat file looks like.

Comment: This reads a little easier for me: 
`$colList = ($cols.Split("\`t") | %{"$_ VARCHAR(100)"} ) -join ","` 

It basically says "Split the first line into an array of items between tabs, append 'VARCHAR (100)' to each one, then join the array items with a comma in between. 
Then `$table = "CREATE TABLE  $file ($colList)"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed something in

$columns = $columns.Replace(" ","")
$columns = $columns.Replace(",","] VARCHAR(100), [")

Or
In the header format inside txt file, did you separate each column name with comma?

Did you check this import using import flat file from ssms?

Comment: It appears my file is tab deiminated - not sure how to change the original code to address that. I tried to remove the first comma after replace in this line of code, $columns = $columns.Replace(",","] VARCHAR(100), [")    but still got the same error

Comment: Hi, I think that below code will work: $columns = $columns.Replace(" ",",")

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you replace

$columns = $columns.Replace(" ","") by
$columns = $columns.Replace("   ",",").... it should work.

Answer (score 1):

How's this for a change:

Get-ChildItem -Path "\unc\filename.tab" | Import-DbaCsv -SqlInstance $SqlInstace -Database databasename -AutoCreateTable  -Delimiter "`t"